# Why axios do not handle with 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Tags: php, react-native, axios

I'm making requests with Axios and everything works correctly, but if there is an error in the PHP API like: "Undefined index:...". Axios doesn't handle the error with 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

```
const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: URL + "/api/",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
            let data = {
              orderList: {
                limit: 10,
                page: page,
                orderby: orderBy,
                search: search
              }
            };
            data = qs.stringify(data);
            let orderList;
            await API.post("api.php", data, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              }
            }).then(response => {
              orderList = response.data;
            }).catch(() => {
              orderList = 'Network Error';
            })
            return orderList;
          },
```

I wanted it to return only the JSON result from the API, if not, trigger catch. However catch is not being triggered.

Comment: headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          } 
did not work @LawrenceCherone

Comment: What's the HTTP status code of the response you get back? 200? 500?

Comment: @ceejayoz 200. Detail: I'm triggering the error in PHP and I'm seeing it in the terminal react native log

Comment: That's why, then. A 200 status won't trigger `catch`. It's not an error; Axios will consider it a success. If you're returning JSON data about the error as 200 responses, you'll have to handle them in the `then` block.

Answer (score -1):

use header like this

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations when you answer a question.